# Setting last row as Frozen in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My grid currently has 40 rows. Only 20 rows can be displayed at a time, so the grid has a scrollbar.

I want to freeze the last row of the DataGridView, but then the scrollbar disappears. How to solve this?

Comment: So you want to set the last row as frozen, but this also gives unwanted behavior so you don't want it? Am I not getting something?

Comment: the last of the 20 shown or the last of all of the 40? What do you mean by frozen exactly, that it should be Enabled=false? That it should stick the the bottom at all times? Can you show what you have tried? Can you show screenshots of expected behavior?

Comment: @Default: there is a property ["frozen"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx) for rows in a DataGridView.

Comment: see i have written a code so every time the last row is always displayed. Now is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `DataGridviewRow.Frozen` property: see documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> This property lets you keep one or several rows of important
>   information in place when a user scrolls through the DataGridView. **All
>   rows above the frozen row are also frozen.**

Which essentially means, if you "freeze" the last row, all rows above the frozen row get frozen too; meaning that the scrollbar gets, because you freeze the last row, removed.

To answer your question; you can not individually "freeze" **only** the last row, this is not in the nature of `Frozen` property.

---

There is a workaround documented in [this document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768632/How-to-fake-freeze-last-row-in-datagridview). However, it is in VB, so you will have to translate this to C# yourself.

Actually looking further I found [this document](http://rixxtech.blogspot.com/2008/06/adding-footer-to-datagridview-component.html), which has a small example in C#. It appears to have bugs but might get you going towards your goal.

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public StatusStrip Footer
    {
        get { return (StatusStrip)this.Controls["Footer"]; }
    }

    private bool _footerVisible;
    [Browsable(false)]
    ///

    /// Sets or Gets the value specifying if a footer bar is shown or not
    ///

    public bool FooterVisible
    {
        get { return _footerVisible; }
        set
        {
            _footerVisible = value;
            this.Controls["Footer"].Visible = _footerVisible;
        }
    }

    public MyDataGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StatusStrip footer = new StatusStrip();
        footer.Name = "Footer";
        footer.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        this.Controls.Add(footer);
        ((StatusStrip)this.Controls["Footer"]).Visible = _footerVisible;
        ((StatusStrip)this.Controls["Footer"]).VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(RDataGridView_VisibleChanged);
        this.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(RDataGridView_Scroll);
        _footerItems = ((StatusStrip)this.Controls["Footer"]).Items;
    }
}
```

The above stated code can be used as a usercontrol and inherits from the `DataGridView`. It then adds a footer which you can fill with the last row of your choice. The scrollbar still will be visible if you set the `Frozen` property of all rows to False.

Comment: @Santarkantos: You are correct, I have edited my answer. And trying to find a workaround, if there is one.