# Freeze last row of datagridview C#.and using datagridview frozen property will freeze all rows

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to display last row of the datagrid at the end of the grid.  My grid has 50 rows and at single screen it shows 20 rows. i want to show the last row at bottom always and displayed.
If i use datagridview.rows[].frozen property whole grid is freezed.

Here is the image of my grid where total  row is at the end it is not displayed.

[image]

I want to show this total row every time as the screen..

[image]

Comment: please include your code.

Comment: May be [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24286710/5326387). Also think about of two different components (one for the last row only).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting last row as Frozen in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286495/setting-last-row-as-frozen-in-datagridview)

Comment: Possibly be duplicate.. but i didn't get solution of my query there. If You think its duplicate please share me the solution which help me

Comment: The question I pointed out seems a straight duplicate of yours. Have you seriously tried to implement the solutions proposed there? Post the code you used, show us what errors did you encounter. Posting 2 images is not enough for us to help you, and this is not a free-code fabric, so you are supposed to show your effort in finding a solution.

Comment: Also, remember that if you want to answer to one of my comments, you have to  call my name with a "@" at the beginning. Otherwise, I will not receive a notification of your comment, and you will never receive my answer. That's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Why don't you just put 2 textboxes underneath the DGV and show the relevant data there? Alternatively add another tiny DGV with just one row.

Comment: i just made the last row frozen = true... it freeze whole grid

Comment: As per the MSDN documentation at [DataGridViewRow.Frozen Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx)... _”This property lets you keep one or several rows of important information in place when a user scrolls through the DataGridView. **All rows above the frozen row are also frozen**.”_. If you set the last row frozen to true then all rows above that row will also be frozen.

Comment: As Tobias Knauss suggest, it appears separating this “Totals” value to a text box outside/beneath the grid would be easier to implement. If you must have this “Total” inside the grid, have you considered moving it to the FIRST row and freeze that row. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the old trick of setting the current cell.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Cells[0];
```

See http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?428877-datagridview-ensuring-a-row-is-visible.

Comment: What will this do with the freezing